# If $G$ is a group and $y \in G$\ $\langle x \rangle$ , then can $\langle y \rangle$ be $G$?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

If $G$ is a group and $e \ne x \in G$ and $y \in G$\  $\langle x \rangle$ , then can $\langle y \rangle$ be $G$  ?

Comment: **Hint:**  You want $G$ to be cyclic, generated by $y$, and you want $\langle x \rangle$ to be something less than all of $G$.

Comment: @hardmath: Cannot understand , elaborate please ... and don't assume $G$ is finite ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried $G = \mathbf{Z}$, $x = 2$ and $y = 1$ before asking ?

Comment: $x = 2$ and $y = 1$, not $x = 1$ and $y = 2$, read again and plug again.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is definitely a correct answer.

Comment: But $1 \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \langle 2 \rangle,$ which is consistent with how the question was asked.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be cyclic (not necessarily finite), but with say $y$ as a generator.  E.g. $G$ could be the infinite cyclic group, but with one generator.

Now $\langle y \rangle$ is by construction all of $G$, but not every element of $G$ is a generator.  Pick $x$ in $G$ that is *not* a generator.  For example, we can take $x=e$ the identity element.

Then $y \in G\setminus\langle x\rangle$, since if $y$ were generated by $x$, then $x$ would generate all of $G$.

Comment: @egreg; Thanks, I got a bit distracted!